# What does importing a module actually do in the context of webpack?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, npm, webpack, webpack-2

I am learning `webpack`, coming from an amateur use of JavaScript in pure browser mode. I will use `bootstrap` and [`moment`](https://momentjs.com/) as examples for highlighting the confusing points.

In pure browser mode, I am addding both CSS and JS components at the bottom of my `<body>` (I removed the full paths or URLs for clarity):

```
(...)
    <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="botstrap.css">
    <script src="moment.js"></script>
    <script src="myownscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When running the app

- the Bootstrap components are loaded (the CSS I use directly in `<div class='some bootstrap class'>`, and the JS which is needed by Bootstrap but which I do not use directly),
- as well as `moment.js` which exposes `moment` I can use in `myownscript.js` (`moment.now()` for instance)

I then discovered `webpack` which is great but I fail to understand [how to use the modules I `import` in my `entry.js` code](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/).

Specifically:

**For bootstrap** I initially tried (after installing it with `npm`)

```
import 'bootstrap'
```

This did not enabled me to use the CSS I normally use in my code, the code looks like there is no Bootstrap applied.

I then tried

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
```

and, behold, Bootstrap is applied. Except for the Javascript part.

Subquestion: should I just `import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'` and it will be used in the same way as with the pure browser experience?

I doubt so because...

**For `moment`:** I initially tried to just

```
import 'moment'
```

But that was not enough. I needed to

```
import 'moment'
Window.moment = moment
```

to expose `moment` to be used as, say, `moment.now()` in my scripts.

**My question: is `import '<module>'` in any way magical or should I just treat the modules installed via `npm` and residing in `node_modules` as a plain repository and `import` them manually?**

If so: what is the purpose of a bare `import '<module>'`?

Comment: I would highly recommend taking an hour (maybe less) and watching the free Webpack course here https://webpack.academy/courses.

Comment: @StephenR.Smith: I use `webpack` daily and I am very happy with it. Does the course you mention address my question? (that it to explain how importing a bare module works, beyond the dependency graph). If so I would gladly watch it, in addition to the courses I had on various other platforms (like Lynda, their course is not bad either)

Comment: It's about 30 minutes, and it covers the structure of the webpack config file and how the test and loader mechanism works, as well as plugins and loader chaining. Once you know how webpack uses the config to inform how it will read your source files, I think you'll have a much clearer understanding of what's happening here.

Comment: @StephenR.Smith: well, as I mentioned I use webpack and therefore have used several chained loaders, outputs dependent on the prod vs dev, etc. It is not "what is import" that I am asking about (and how it gets bundled) - it is how `import 'module'` works with the files in `node_modules`, as opposed to importing them themselves. The body of my question, in short. Now - if this is addressed in the course I will have a look (there will always be something interesting, particularly looking at the author) but if you could suggest where the answer to my question is it would be fantastic.

Comment: @StephenR.Smith: I went through the course and while it is neat as an introduction it does not address my question (or if I missed this TIA for pointing me out where the answer is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is available through the `import <module>` depends on what is exposed by the module `package.json` `main` entry.

For bootstrap, this is `dist/js/bootstrap.js`. But this file does not export anything, and `import 'bootstrap'` will load all of Bootstrap's jQuery plugins onto the jQuery object. Also you have to `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'` manually.

Here is a minimal webpack setup to make this work.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^3.4.1"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: "./scripts.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, ""),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        { loader: "style-loader" },
        { loader: "css-loader" }
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
      use: 'file-loader?name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]'
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
     $: 'jquery',
     jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  ]
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Test</h1>
 <div id="myModal">myModal</div>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and scripts.js

```
import 'bootstrap'
import moment from 'moment'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'

console.log(moment.now(), $('#myModal').modal(), jQuery)
```

`jQuery` is loaded globally via the webpack `Provide` plugin and 
`Bootstrap`'s javascript [is attached to the `jQuery` object](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download-npm).

And from the command line:

```
$ npm install 
$ webpack
```